# Make "make" rerun only the parts of a pipeline that come after what has changed

Tags: makefile

I'm using `make`, I believe `GNU Make` on WSL. I'm using it for data science, building on `cookiecutter-datascience`.

In my mind before I started using `make`, the point of it was to keep track of which parts of a pipeline have changed, and only rerun the stages in the pipeline *after it*.

Here's a snippet from the makefile:

```
## Install Python Dependencies
requirements: test_environment
    pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
    pip install -r requirements.txt

## Make Dataset
data: requirements
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py
```

When I run `make data`, it doesn't just rerun the data part of the pipeline and the succeeding stages, but it also reruns `make requirements` and `make test_environment`. But this is the *opposite* of what I want. Those stages come *before*, not *after*. If I have an expensive pipeline, I obviously don't want to rerun it over and over again.

In my case, I want it so that: If one of the raw (un-preprocessed) data files changes, I want it to rerun the data preprocessing. This should not include things like tracking whether the libraries have changed, because those steps logically preceed the data preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
## Install Python Dependencies
requirements.done: test_environment.done
    pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    touch requirements.done

## Make Dataset
data: requirements.done
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py
```

Make compares date of last modification of files. Your `requirements`, `test_environment`... are not files, they are what is called "*phony*" targets. As they don't exist, make tries to build them as soon as they are needed. If you want make to discover that something is up to date and does not need to be rebuilt, you must use files. The proposed solution uses empty, dummy, files (the `*.done` files), instead of your phony targets. These files are used only to store the date of actions in their last modification times.

Of course, you can use files named `requirements`, `test_environment`... if you prefer. The `.done` extension is just a way to identify these files as dummy markers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: To be more explicit about this: make determines which steps in a pipeline have been run by comparing timestamps of files on the filesystem.  That's the only "database" of what operations have previously been run that it has (in your example above, how do you imagine that make should know that the `requirements` step in your pipeline was already run?)  If the steps in your pipeline don't create files naturally, you need to make them yourself using `touch` or similar.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks. That makes sense